# Netbeans and Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, tomcat7

I deleted all my versions of Netbeans on my computer and even fully cleared the userdr and caches via terminal and when I go to download Netbeans (again) as a fresh install it still recalls my preferences (which I don't want it to) regarding where my Tomcat is located which is an incorrect file.

All I want is to clear any remnant of Netbeans and Tomcat and do a fresh Java EE download!

I already tried this...
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUninstallMac

Answer (score 0):

For mac users: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUninstallMac --this is erroneous when instructing on how to delete the app support via terminal (the cache is correct however). Manually go into Library/Application Support/Netbeans and drag to trash. Also when installing be sure to select the "Customize" button to be prompted to choose Tomcat (versus Glassfish which is the default install).